# How to return a SelectedItems value when listbox items are inside an "add_SelectedValueChanged" block

Tags: powershell, listbox

After selecting an option from the drop down list ($RCVROption), when choosing an option from the list provided ($listBox), the $listBox.SelectedItems values are always Null. How do I get those values to assign to variable $x

This is the script I tried, my goal is to have the text from $listBox.SelectedItems to be used as a value that represents a file name, so that when you select an option from the list, and click OK, it runs that file.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

 
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = 'DMP Receiver Tail'
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,300)
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
 
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(115,220)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)
 
$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(190,220)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)
 
$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(60,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label.Text = 'Which Receiver Would You Like To Tail?:'
$form.Controls.Add($label)
 
$RCVROption = new-object System.Windows.Forms.combobox
$RCVROption.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(20,40)
$RCVROption.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(335,30)
[void] $RCVROption.Items.Add('Receiver 560')
[void] $RCVROption.Items.Add('Receiver 2560')
$RCVROption.tabIndex = '0'
$RCVROption.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDownList;
 $RCVROption.add_SelectedValueChanged(
 {
    
 if($RCVROption.SelectedItem -eq 'Receiver 560')
 {

$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Listbox
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(40,100)
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,80)
 
$listBox.SelectionMode = 'MultiExtended'
 
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('DMP-560-Line1')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('DMP-560-Line2')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('DMP-560-Line3')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('DMP-560-Line4')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('DMP-560-Line5')
$form.Controls.Add($listBox)
} 

ELSEIF($RCVROption.SelectedItem -eq 'Receiver 2560')
{
$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Listbox
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(40,100)
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,80)
 
$listBox.SelectionMode = 'MultiExtended'
 
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('DMP-2560-Line1')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('DMP-2560-Line2')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('DMP-2560-Line3')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('DMP-2560-Line4')
[void] $listBox.Items.Add('DMP-2560-Line5')
$form.Controls.Add($listBox)
}
}
)
$form.Controls.Add($RCVROption)
$form.Topmost = $true
$result = $form.ShowDialog()
 

 
if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
   $x = $listBox.SelectedItems
    $Fpath = 'D:\Toolbar\On Call\DMP-Tail\' + $x + '.exe'
    Start-process -filepath $FPath
     $Fpath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I'm guessing you come from a C# background.  PowerShell does something weird where it can normally reach outside of script block's scope `{code in scriptblock}` and use variables that already exist at the time the scriptblock is executed.  But it can't easily create or add new variables in the parent/outer scope.

Your code is creating `$listBox` inside the `$RCVROption.add_SelectedValueChanged({code in scriptblock})` event scriptblock, and adding it to the controls for the form, so it continues to exist in the form, but not at the global/script scope of the your code.

I've reworked your code in a format that I've been learning over the last year.  Everything you had should still be there, only in a more condensed form.  You don't have to use this format, but I personally really like it. How PowerShell converts things like `"Cancel"` into `[System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel` is a bit of a mistery to me, but this type of conversion seems very reliable.

This version of the code creates the `$listBox` prior to firing of the `$RCVROption.add_SelectedValueChanged` event, clears the items in `$listBox`, and then populates the ListBox with the new values.  The values are in an array, and piped into the `[void] $listBox.Items.Add($_)` command, executing it once per item in the array.

```
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Drawing
Set-StrictMode -Version 3.0

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
[Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$form = [Form]@{
    Text            = 'DMP Receiver Tail'
    Size            = "400,300"
    StartPosition   = 'CenterScreen'
    Topmost         = $true
}

$OKButton = [Button]@{
    DialogResult    = "OK"
    Location        = "115,220"
    Size            = "75,23"
    Text            = 'OK'
}
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = [Button]@{
    DialogResult    = "Cancel"
    Location        = "190,220"
    Size            = "75,23"
    Text            = 'Cancel'
}
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$label = [Label]@{
    Location    = "60,20"
    Size        = "280,20"
    Text        = 'Which Receiver Would You Like To Tail?:'
}
$form.Controls.Add($label)

$RCVROption = [ComboBox]@{
    DropDownStyle = "DropDownList"
    Location    = "20,40"
    Size        = "335,30"
    tabIndex    = '0'
}
[void] $RCVROption.Items.Add('Receiver 560')
[void] $RCVROption.Items.Add('Receiver 2560')

$listBox = [Listbox]@{
    Location        = "40,100"
    SelectionMode   = 'MultiExtended'
    Size            = "260,80"
}
$form.Controls.Add($listBox)


$RCVROption.add_SelectedValueChanged({
    if($RCVROption.SelectedItem -eq 'Receiver 560') {
        $listBox.Items.Clear()
        'DMP-560-Line1', 'DMP-560-Line2', 'DMP-560-Line3', 'DMP-560-Line4', 'DMP-560-Line5' | ForEach-Object {
            [void] $listBox.Items.Add($_)
        }
    }
    elseif($RCVROption.SelectedItem -eq 'Receiver 2560') {
        $listBox.Items.Clear()
        'DMP-2560-Line1', 'DMP-2560-Line2', 'DMP-2560-Line3', 'DMP-2560-Line4', 'DMP-2560-Line5' | ForEach-Object {
            [void] $listBox.Items.Add($_)
        }
    }
})
$form.Controls.Add($RCVROption)

$result = $form.ShowDialog()


if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
    $x = $listBox.SelectedItems
    $Fpath = 'D:\Toolbar\On Call\DMP-Tail\' + $x + '.exe'
    Start-process -filepath $FPath
    $Fpath
}
```

Comment: Wow...thank you. I've never had any training, no one to even talk to...everything learned by reading manuals and a whole lot of trial and error. I signed up last night, and this is the first question I ever asked. I half expected it to get a response. This is the first GUI I attempted to make and your method is definitely different than the manuals I've read. Thank you for your time. This works great.

Comment: @Zagnut119, glad this helped!  I like this way due to the readability, at least I can read it easier.  Unfortunately, I don't know of a resource that teaches how to create WinForms like this in PowerShell.  Instead, I've been learning little by little from people, mostly here on StackOverFlow.  An interesting note, creating a PSCustomObject can done the same way as creating the controls on a form `$Var = [PSCustomObject]@{ Name1 = 'Value1' ; Name2 = 'Value2'}`  I think this somehow relates to "Splatting", but still learning and not sure.

Comment: Is there a reason why you included:
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.Drawing
in addition to:
Add-Type -AssemblyName SystemWindows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Does it add anything?

Comment: And Yes, I use [PSCustomObject] all the time, probably exists in the majority of my utilities that do remote lookups, or to create automated employee import spreadsheets for the services we use here.
I like to use it like this:
Import-csv -path <Filepathof.csv> | foreach-object { $variable=$_.headername ; $Hostnames=$_.Hostnames  <--Normally naming the variable the same as the header $Variable2=(Get-Wmiobject -Computername $Hostnames blah blah blah) ; [PScustomObject][Ordered]@{ 'New Header'=$variable ; 'Hostname'=$Hostnames ; 'Computer Info'=$Variable3 } | Out-Gridview -passthru | Clip

Comment: @Zagnut119, just ran a test and `using namespace System.Drawing` isn't needed.  But `using namespace System.Windows.Forms` allows you to replace commands such as `$OKButton = [System.Windows.Forms.Button]@{...}` with `$OKButton = [Button]@{...}`.  Anywhere a type is prefixed with `System.Windows.Forms.`, you can now reduce it to just the type name without the extra path info.  `Add-Type` is making the library available, but `using namespace` is making a sub part of the library available without using then entire namespace address.

Comment: @Zagnut119, in general, if I only need to use an item buried in a library once or twice, I often will just use the full namespace path and neglect using the `using namespace` command.  But in your code it `System.Windows.Forms.` is used around 12 times - btw, I missed the last use of it in `if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {`.  As for `System.Drawing.`, that was actually eliminated in your code by using strings like `"260,80"` in place of explicit references such as `System.Drawing.Size(260,80)`, but again, how does PowerShell know we want to call `size(w,h)`?????